# I'm a sudoer and also NOT in sudoers file somehow?

Tags: sudo

I'm trying to run `sudo apt-get update`.

I will paste my last output from me trying to 'add' myself to sudoers file (which I figured I was on, but kept getting errors saying I wasn't...)

```
timothy@AMDx6:~$ sudo nano /etc/inittab
[sudo] password for timothy: 
timothy is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
timothy@AMDx6:~$ su
Password: 
root@AMDx6:/home/timothy# visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers.tmp unchanged
root@AMDx6:/home/timothy# sudo adduser timothy
adduser: The user `timothy' already exists.
root@AMDx6:/home/timothy# exit
exit
timothy@AMDx6:~$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for timothy: 
timothy is not in the sudoers file.  This incident will be reported.
timothy@AMDx6:~$
```

Comment: You should read manual page for `sudoers` file format and how to add yourself to it. There are plenty examples around the net, just google `add myself to sudoers`

Comment: see, that is just IT... I AM able to sudo.... but not sys updates for some reason...

Comment: What makes you think that you are able to sudo? In your question, you've shown the use of `su`, but not `sudo`.

Comment: apparently i forgot the file that I add sudoers in.I asked this a LONG time ago, the recent down-votes are inappropriate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sudo` is not saying the user doesn't exist, just that it is not in the sudoers file.

`adduser` is a script to add a system user, not an entry in the sudoers file.

To do what you want, you need to grant rights to `timothy` with `visudo`.  Check `man sudoers` for details.

Comment: Yes this was PRECISELY what the issue was. I also wanted sudo to make a nifty log, should I ever find the need to review what I did that made an obvious problem. In the end, what you suggested was PRECISELY what I did!

Answer (score 2):

`sudo adduser timothy` creates a user called timothy.  It doesn't create a sudo user called timothy.  To give timothy some sudo privileges you need to edit the sudoers file, e.g. add this entry to permit timothy to run any command as root, without re-entering his password.

```
timothy ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: ALL
```

Comment: yeah... the re-entry of the password is a security feature I WONT circumvent. It exists to get a person to STOP before they do. It's a 2nd chance instead of an "ahh F@#k!"

Comment: Indeed.  Useful if you're scripting and don't want it to go interactive.  But reduces security.

Comment: rhank you though. It is indeed situations like THIS that make me go"ahh F@#K!" when I realize that I am, indeed NOT in the sudoers file!

Answer (score 2):

You say "I AM able to `sudo`.... but not sys updates for some reason". But the transcript you posted shows that you cannot, as `sudo nano` fails with `not in sudoers`.

To fix, check which group(s) you're in: `groups timothy`. Then grep `/etc/sudoers` for either `timothy` or any of the groups that showed up. I'm pretty sure you'll find out none of them do.

Then check which admin group *is* permitted: run `visudo` as root and look for something like:

```
## Allows people in group wheel to run all commands
%wheel  ALL=(ALL)       ALL
```

and add `timothy` to that group, for example: `usermod -G wheel -a timothy`